# yii toggle maintenance mode ON/OFF

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to make a maintenance mode in my website, I want to put a button that only the admin can see to toggle the maintenance mode ON/OFF.

This allow to admin continue seeing the web but the rest of the visitors not.

I have read about catchAllRequest, creating a file and renaming it when is necessary, but I cant make it work.

I have tried underconstruct extension, but I dont know how to toggle ON/OFF.

This is what I have at the moment.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $location = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/protected/config/maintenanceON.txt';
        $new = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/protected/config/maintenanceOFF.txt';
        Yii::app()->session['secret'] = "password";
        rename($location,$new);
        $this->renderPartial("index");
    }
```

**CONFIG/MAIN.PHP :**

```
'catchAllRequest'=>file_exists(
        dirname(__FILE__).'/maintenanceON.txt') && 
            !(isset(Yii::app()->session['secret']) && Yii::app()->session['secret']=="password") ?
                array('maintenance/index') : null,
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this in components/Controller.php:

```
public function beforeAction() {
    if(Yii::app()->params['maintenance'] == true && Yii::app()->user->id != 1) {
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'Under Maintenance');
    }
}
```

Put this in config/main.php:

```
'params' => array(
    'maintenance' => true,
),
```

Comment: But how can I keep the admin online?

Comment: do simple check by role, add in UserIdentity setState('role', $oUser->role) and then check in beforeAction() using it

Comment: But that way I have to change manualy the params in the config, the thing is to make a button to activate and desactivate de maintenance mode.

Comment: But I know where to put it, I dont know how to toggle ON/OFF xD

Comment: I used: https://github.com/ekaragodin/MaintenanceMode extension, and I rename the file with false/true, DONE!

Comment: It is better to throw new CHttpException(503, 'Service Unavailable') for maintenance case. It will prevent search engine crawling 404 pages. It also a good idea to provide Retry-After header.